# Uses-permissions for NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I have a BroadcastReceiver and I use it for some control on outgoing calls. Here is part of Android.manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"
    android:priority="0" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Obviously, some of uses permissions are redundant. Which ones and how will I figure it out in the future when I'll be using others `android.intent.action`'s?